# opencl:can different queues on the same device execute kernels in parallel?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I created 2 queues on a GPU device,and want to execute the kernels in parallel.This is no need to set events between kernels in different queues,but the kernels in tne same queue must be executed in order.In addition,I created 2 CPU threads,each CPU thread control 1 queue,and the CPU threads are executed parallel.Now It seems that the kernels between different queues were not executed in parallel.So anybody can give me some advices?

Thanks for your answer.Here are some information about my platform.[image]

Information about Driver[image]

Os:Centos 5.X

Answer (score 2):

Most GPUs are not capable to run multiple kernels at the same time. It is just an hardware limitation, not a software problem. You can run the execution of multiple kernels in parallel but on multiple GPUs (i.e. multiple OpenCL devices).

Anyway many GPUs are able, in your scenario, to overlap memory transfers (CPU <=> GPU) and kernel execution. It is up to the OpenCL driver but I have seen AMD driver to overlap memory transfers from one queue and kernel executions from an another.

Answer (score 1):

There may be just one compute unit on the device that will cause kernels to be executed one at a time. If so, the kernels may have to be partitioned by the host application and queued alternately to allow for their "parallel" execution. The number of compute units is returned by `clGetDeviceInfo` for `CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS` parameter.

If there is more than one compute unit, the device may support partitioning if the value of the device parameter `CL_DEVICE_PARTITION_MAX_SUB_DEVICES` is greater that 1. In this case, the device can be "split" into several sub-devices (e.g. two) using `clCreateSubDevices` with separate command queues. Each sub-device will execute kernels independently from (and in parallel with) other sub-devices.

Note that unbalanced load of the sub-devices may need to be addressed by the host application if more optimal load is desired.